# Derivative of a smooth, monotone function at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a monotone, infinitely differentiable function whose limit at infinity is zero.

Is it true that the derivative of $f(x)$ has limit zero as $x$ tends to infinity?

My guess is that the derivative of $f(x)$ may not have a limit at infinity.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right the limit of $f'$ may not exist. Exhibit a counter example can be made using a function $h$ on $[0,1]$ that is increasing, infinitely differentiable and such that 
$$ h(0) = 0, \ h(1) = 1, \ h^{(k)}(0) = h^{(k)}(1) = 0, \ \forall k =1,2,...   $$

Then define
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac{h(x) \  1 \{ x < n \}}{2^n} - 1,   $$
where $1$ is the indicator function.

Now find such a function $h$ is the hard part, I think we can work something out using $ \exp(- \frac 1 x)$...

Comment: roger, to construct such a function take a piecewise linear function which is $0$ on $(-\infty,\frac{1}{3}]$ and $1$ on $[\frac{2}{3},\infty)$ and convolve it with a standard bump function supported on $[-\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{10}]$ (for example the function which has kernel $e^{\frac{-1}{1-(\frac{x^2}{100})}}$ on $(-\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{10})$ and 0 elsewhere and integrates to 1).

Comment: I also think you may need that $h$ to be $h(\frac{x}{n})$ or something, otherwise it won't be defined on the inputs.